# generate statistical table to complete and then review,How can I generate this exact table?

Tags: probability-or-statistics, list-manipulation, data, visualization

Good morning everyone

I want to generate a data table model with intervals (between 5 and 15) following Sturges rule
I want to generate a data table model with intervals (between 5 and 15) following the Sturges rule, for school purposes where minimum and maximum random entries between 0 and 999 are generated and distributed in intervals with equal amplitudes and closed on the left and open on the right [ a----b[ and that gives me the frequency for each interval.and all this put it in a table to be filled by the student, the idea is that in each program run a different one is generated.
and below the solution of the solved table, where xi=class mark ,fr = relative frequency ,Fi= cumulative frequency Fr% = cumulative frequency percentage and fr% = relative frequency percentage and also LI----LS lower and upper limits of each interval.
I would appreciate it very much
I attach an image of the idea

EDIT:
Hello, I am a high school teacher and I want to have a program that generates a different semi-empty data table each time I run the program, with the data in the intervals and the frequency of them for my students to fill in the rest, and in addition to that the result of the complete table generated by mathematics for my correction purposes.
[image]

Comment: I don't really understand the question, but maybe you can use [HistogramList](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/HistogramList.html) which supports Sturges rule to generate the bin widths and counts.

Comment: @ Rohit Namjosh_ see edit.